# Output based on input keywords

Tags: python, python-2.7

So. I have code that takes a users input and deals with it. It takes there name and of the name Sean is their name, it asks them which Sean it is. I want it so that of neither of the Sean listed are entered, it will say 'I don't know that Sean' but its buggy and won't work. Any help?
Heres the code;

```
name = raw_input ("What's your name?")

if Sean in name:    
    name1 = raw_input("Downey or Paul?")    
else:    
    print ('Hi %s') % (name)    
if Downey in name1:    
    print ("Hi Sean Downey")    
if Paul in name1:    
    print ("Hi Sean Paul")    
else:    
    print ("I don't know that Sean")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working version of your code with some minor changes that I'll explain below

```
name = raw_input ("What's your name?")

if 'Sean' in name:    
    name1 = raw_input("Downey or Paul?")        
    if 'Downey' in name1:    
        print ("Hi Sean Downey")
        x = raw_input("Did you know that the name is irish?")
        if x == 'yea':
            print ('oh cool')
    elif 'Paul' in name1:    
        print ("Hi Sean Paul")    
    else:    
        print ("I don't know that Sean")
else:    
    print ('Hi %s') % (name)
```

First, as user2612566 mentioned, you are confusing variables with string literals. To check if the user input Sean as name you should check `if 'Sean' in name:` because the input is converted to a string.

Second, your code was ordered so that even if Sean was not in `name`, it would print `I don't know that Sean` because of the `else` block on the bottom of your code, I changed that by moving the 2nd and 3rd `if` blocks into the first `if` block.

Third, you checke `if Downey in name1:` but `name1` only exists if your code enters the first if, so if it doesn't enter the first if, your code will fail because it cannot find the variable `name1`. This is also fixed by moving those `if`s into the first `if`

Comment: How would I make it so that if the user said Downey, it would ask them do they know that the name is irish and if they said yea, it would say 'oh cool'

Comment: @user3727382 see the edit, I inserted some lines. A new raw_input that stores the answer in `x` and a new `if` that checks the input and prints 'oh cool' if the input was 'yeah'

Comment: How Do I make it possible for her to understand both yea, yes and yeah for x == 'yea':

Comment: @ImSeanDowney if x in ['yea', 'yes', 'yeah']

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing string literals with variable names.  It appears that you want to test whether `'Sean' in name1` rather than `Sean in name1`.

Also, your third 'if' statement should be an elif -- see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271712/difference-between-multiple-ifs-and-elifs-python)

Your ifs also aren't properly nested for the results you want.

Fixed code:

```
name = raw_input ("What's your name?")

if 'Sean' in name:    
    name1 = raw_input("Downey or Paul?")
    if 'Downey' in name1:    
        print ("Hi Sean Downey")    
    elif 'Paul' in name1:    
        print ("Hi Sean Paul")    
    else:    
        print ("I don't know that Sean")  
else:    
    print ('Hi %s') % (name)
```

Comment: How do i make it so that if neither known surname is entered, is says 'I don't know that Sean'

Comment: Make the corresponding change to `if Downey in name1` and `if Paul in name1` (as well as changing that if to elif) and it should work the way you want it to.

Comment: It works but if I enter a name that ain't sean it says/ Hi (name) / Hi Sean Paul