# The tasks `elif` performs otherwise cannot be achieved by 'if'

Tags: python

Suppose a minimal control flow case:

```
    x = input("Numaral:  ")
    y = input("Numaral:  ")
    if x < y:
        print('x is less than y.')
    elif x > y:
        print('x is greater than y.')
    else:
        print('x is equal to y.')
```

Run and come by

```
    $ python3 draft.py
    Numaral:  3
    Numaral:  3
    x is equal to y.
```

When substitute `elif` with `if`

```
    x = input("Numaral:  ")
    y = input("Numaral:  ")
    if x < y:
        print('x is less than y.')
    if x > y:
        print('x is greater than y.')
    else:
        print('x is equal to y.')
```

It's logic still perfectly correct.

```
    $ python3 draft.py
    Numaral:  4
    Numaral:  2
    x is greater than y.
```

I have searched and read answers to distinguish `if` and `elif`,
It seem that the arguments did not hit home to convince the necessity of `elif`'s existence, since the `elif`s could be  replaced by `if` directly or indirectly.

Is there a case when a control flow logic can only be addressed by `elif` , or
if the `elif` is absent, the control flow is flawed.

Comment: I seek no difference in both of your code. What are you trying to achieve here and what is the error you are facing?

Comment: In the first, `elif` case, if `x` is lower than `y` no other evaluations will be performed while in the second case the second evaluation will be performed regardless of `x` and `y` values. Also, try setting `x` to `2` and `y` to `4` and see what happens with your second script (hint: it will print that `x` is both less and equal to `y`).

Comment: Just a hint: Since you are using python3 you probably forgot to convert your input into an int: `x = int(input("Numaral:  "))`. Otherwise you will get unexpected results if you input "19" and "2" for example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`elif` is just a nice way of expressing `else: if`, but this means your equivalence is wrong:

```
if x < y:
    print('x is less than y.')
if x > y:
    print('x is greater than y.')
else:
    print('x is equal to y.')
```

evaluates the `if x > y` test even when it has already taken the `x < y` branch. Using `elif` allows you to express your knowledge that these branches are mutually exclusive (for sane definitions of `<`), so the code *should* be

```
if x < y:
    print('x is less than y.')
else:
    if x > y:
        print('x is greater than y.')
    else:
        print('x is equal to y.')
```

you can see how this is less readable, and scales very poorly with long `elif` chains (which give deeply-nested code).

For an example where the mutual-exclusion property is more important, consider something like

```
if x == None:
    print "x is None"
elif x.method() < 42:
    print "x is not None, and method() is < 42"
else:
    print "x is not None but method() >= 42"
```

where replacing `elif` with `if` would raise an exception (if x really is `None`, you can't call a method on it)

Answer (score 4):

Your situation uses cases that are mutually  exclusive. Either `x < y` *or* `x > y`. These two don't overlap. That's the reason why `if/elif` and `if/if` behave as you observe.

Consider a situation where the cases are *not* mutually exclusive.

```
if x > 100:
  do_something_for_large_x()
elif x > 50:
  do_something_for_medium_x()
else:
  do_something_for_other_x()
```

Only one of the three `do_something_for_...` functions will be executed.

If you replace the `elif` with `if` both `do_something_for_large_x` and `do_something_for_medium_x` will be executed because the branch conditions overlap.

Answer (score 2):

Your second code is broken.

```
x = input("Numaral:  ")
y = input("Numaral:  ")
if x < y:
    print('x is less than y.')
if x > y:
    print('x is greater than y.')
else:
    print('x is equal to y.')
```

If I enter `x` as 0 and `y` as 19, it will say

```
x is less than y.
```

AND

```
x is equal to y.
```

With `elif` the `else` block is executed **only** if none of the `elif` (and the first `if`) blocks are.

Comment: @FlyingTeller I thought I had

Answer (score 0):

`if, elif, elif, elif, else` is one single statement evaluated by the computer;
while `if, if, if, if` is four separated statements;
`if, if, if, else` is three separated statements.

[if statement - Difference Between Multiple If's and Elif's Python - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271712/difference-between-multiple-ifs-and-elifs-python)