# `else` branch only pair to its nearest 'if'

Tags: python

Suppose the following minimal code:

```
    x = input("Numeral:  ")
    y = input("Numeral:  ")
    if x < y:
        print(f'{x} is less than {y}.')
    if x > y:
        print(f'{x} is greater than {y}.')
    else:
        print(f'{x} is equal to {y}.')
```

I feed it and come by

```
    $ python3 draft.py
    Numeral:  1
    Numeral:  0
    1 is greater than 0.
```

It runs properly, then change the order to input:

```
    $ python3 draft.py
    Numeral:  0
    Numeral:  1
    0 is less than 1.
    0 is equal to 1.
```

The else branch was executed.

Does `else` branch only pair to its nearest 'if'?
What's the mechanism behind it?

Comment: `Does else branch only pair to its nearest 'if'?` Yes. Change the second `if` to an `elif` and it will work.

Comment: You already asked people about this today https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49627409/the-tasks-elif-performs-otherwise-cannot-be-achieved-by-if. Why not edit your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The tasks \`elif\` performs otherwise cannot be achieved by 'if'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49627409/the-tasks-elif-performs-otherwise-cannot-be-achieved-by-if)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it does - the closest `if` with matching indentation, which is how `Python` compiles. It wouldn't make sense in your example:

```
if x < y:
    print(f'{x} is less than {y}.')
if x > y:
    print(f'{x} is greater than {y}.')
else:
    print(f'{x} is equal to {y}.')
```

for the `else` to reference `x<y`, from a readers point of view. It would be the same in any language (with braces). Closest to what you mean but wouldn't make sense for your example:

```
if something:
    print("something")
    if otherThing:
        print("that")
else: print("otherwise!")
```

Now it's clear the `else` belongs to the first `if`. This is not Python specific at all. If you want a triple check:

```
if x > y:
     ...
elif x < y:
     ...
else:
     ...
```

`if (else if) else` construct - that's the way all languages handle this, not just Python. This is the same as:

```
if x > y:
     ...
else:
    if x < y:
        ...
    else:
        ...
```

which makes clear where each `else` belongs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `else` only refers to the last if written.
You might want to use `elif` instead of the 2nd `if`, which will break the loop if the condition on the first `if` is met.

```
    x = input("Numeral:  ")
    y = input("Numeral:  ")
    if x < y:
        print(f'{x} is less than {y}.')
    elif x > y:
        print(f'{x} is greater than {y}.')
    else:
        print(f'{x} is equal to {y}.')
```

Answer (score 0):

python's syntax omits some logic details, if expressed in shell code

```
    if (( x < y)); then
        echo "$y is less than $x"
    fi #indicate to terminate the first if
    if (( x > y)); then
        echo "$x is greater than $y."
    else
        echo "$x is equal to $y."
    fi #mark the end of second if
```

It's clear that chain `if, if, if` is multiple tasks, while `if, elif, elif, else` is single task.

Answer (score -2):

EDIT: Mea culpa, it's `elif` not `else if`in python.

Second `if` should be an `elif`.

basically:

```
if -> if this is true : do that,
elif -> else if this second expression is true: do that,
else -> if everything is false : do that,
```