# How to prioritize a condition over another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, web-scraping

I've written a script to parse a link available within the visible text `contact` or `about` from each webpage. However, when I run my script I can see that my scraper always goes for parsing the link within `about`. It parses the link within `contact` only when `about` is not available. How can i make my script do the opposite, I meant it will look for the link connected to `contact` instead of `about`. If `contact` is not available then only it will parse `about`. I tried the below way to get it done but it is doing the way I described.

This is my try:

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

links = (
    "http://www.mount-zion.biz/",
    "http://www.latamcham.org/",
    "http://www.innovaprint.com.sg/",
    "http://www.cityscape.com.sg/"
    )

def Get_Link(site):
    res = requests.get(site)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select("a[href]"):
        if "contact" in item.text.lower():
            abslink = urljoin(site,item['href']) ##I thought the script prioritizes the first condition but I am wrong
            print(abslink)
            break
        else:
            if "about" in item.text.lower():
                abslink = urljoin(site,item['href'])
                print(abslink)
                break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for link in links:
        Get_Link(link)
```

Is there any way to prioritize a condition based on it's availability?
The bottom line is I wanna get the link connected to `contact`. if it is not available then the script will look for the link connected to `about`.

Comment: You marked this as duplicate considering the difference between multiple `if's` and `elif's` statements whereas my question was the priority over another @jpp. Did I write my post in hebrew?

Comment: No, but maybe I would understand you better if you did!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `else`. Use few `if` instead. Also check [what's difference between if, elif and else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271712/difference-between-multiple-ifs-and-elifs-python).

Your function should look like this:

```
def Get_Link(site):
    res = requests.get(site)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select("a[href]"):
        if "contact" in item.text.lower() or "about" in item.text.lower():
            abslink = urljoin(site,item['href']) 
            print(abslink)
            break
```

You can't use your `break` statements as they break the program's block and second `if` never triggers.

Also notice that in Python we have [convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)) to name methods/functions in snake_case like this: `my_function()` or `my_method()` and class names in CamelCase like this: `MyClass`.

### EDIT:

Ok, it seems like your code is more complicated, because you run loop inside another loop. So basically you have few options:

- Make `if "contact"` loop first, and if it fail in all cases go with "about"
- Place some flags in your code to control `if` statements
- Write it using functions

Or hack it:

```
def Get_Link(site):
    res = requests.get(site)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select("a[href]"):
        if "contact" in item.text.lower():
            abslink = urljoin(site,item['href'])
            print(abslink)
            return 0 # Exit from function
    for item in soup.select("a[href]"):
        if "about" in item.text.lower():
            abslink = urljoin(site,item['href'])
            print(abslink)
            return 0
```

Comment: I tried your solution but the result is still the same. If I comment out the portion after `else` block from my above script then the script does parse the "contact" link from each webpage but I would like to keep both the conditions active within my script so that if one is missing another will be of use. Any other suggestion to do the trick? Thanks.

Comment: @Topto I've edited answer. Try now.

Comment: Yeah I see that. I am sure you didn't notice what result it produces. There is no difference between the result what my earlier script and your suggested script produces. The result both the script produces `http://www.mount-zion.biz/index.html
http://www.latamcham.org/about-us-2/
http://www.innovaprint.com.sg/about.html
http://www.cityscape.com.sg/?page_id=27` I EXPECTED TO HAVE THE FOLLOWING: `http://www.mount-zion.biz/contactus.html
http://www.latamcham.org/contact-us/
http://www.innovaprint.com.sg/contact.html
http://www.cityscape.com.sg/?page_id=37`.

Comment: @Topto. Ok, I've checked. As I suggested the problem is in your `break` statements. They exit your program from `for` block, and another `if` never triggers.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. However, this time the result becomes completely horrible. I expected to have 4 links populated from the four sites I've mentioned above but It gives me 13 links. Most importantly it gives all the links connected to both `about` and `contact`. If that is so then I do not see any necessity of using `conditional statement` here. I'm still wondering how this problem similar to the one leading to the duplicate link. Thanks.

Comment: @Topto ok, now your `break` logic should be the same. You could also use earlier version and use some flags there or even make another function, there are many, many ways to achieve your program flow.

Comment: I'm highly indebted to you for your kind and sweet effort @Qback. This is the approach I tried in the first place before creating this post. However, It does gives 4 links but none of them connected to `contact`; rather, they all are connected to `about`. That is why I questioned how to prioritize the first condition, as in `contact`. Thanks again.

Comment: @Topto ok, I understood. You have loop in loop, it complicated this case a little. But there are still many ways to control your program flow, just invent your one. I gave you an example

Comment: No damn way!! It did the trick. Your answer deserves a checkmark along with an upvote. Much obliged.

Comment: @Topto Thanks ;). Remember that you can still do it in some more elegant ways if you want :).