# Python Logic Code: AND, NAND, OR, NOR, XOR, XNOR, & NOT simulation

Tags: python, function, boolean, logic, boolean-logic

I'm trying to figure out why my code isn't working. Why are some of my logic gates, like `OR`, not giving me the correct output? Take the `OR` gate for example. When I run the code and pass in `1` as the value for `A` and `B`, the output is still `False`. I have tried tweaking it and it still gives me `False` as the output.

Below is an example of what I did so far:

```
aInput = int(input('Enter value for A: '))
bInput = int(input('Enter value for B: '))

#AND Gate
if aInput == 1 and bInput == 1:
    ANDGate = "True"
    ANDGateNum = 1
else:
    ANDGate = "False"
    ANDGateNum = 0

print('AND Gate output is', ANDGate, 'or', ANDGateNum)

#NAND Gate
if aInput == 1 and bInput == 1:
    NANDGate = "False"
    NANDGateNum = 0
else:
    NANDGate = "True"
    NANDGateNum = 1

print('NAND Gate output is', NANDGate, 'or', NANDGateNum)

#OR Gate
if aInput == 1 and bInput == 1:
    ORGate = "True"
    ORGateNum = 1
if aInput == 1 and bInput == 0:
    ORGate = "True"
    ORGateNum = 1
if aInput == 0 and bInput == 1:
    ORGate = "True"
    ORGateNum = 1
else:
    ORGate = "False"
    ORGateNum = 0

print('OR Gate output is', ORGate, 'or', ORGateNum)

#NOR Gate
if aInput == 1 and bInput == 1:
    NORGate = "False"
    NORGateNum = 0
if aInput == 1 and bInput == 0:
    NORGate = "False"
    NORGateNum = 0
if aInput == 0 and bInput == 1:
    NORGate = "False"
    NORGateNum = 0
else:
    NORGate = "True"
    NORGateNum = 1

print('NOR Gate output is', NORGate, 'or', NORGateNum)

#XNOR Gate
if aInput == 1 and bInput == 1:
    XNORGate = "True"
    XNORGateNum = 1
if aInput == 1 and bInput == 0:
    XNORGate = "False"
    XNORGateNum = 0
if aInput == 0 and bInput == 1:
    XNORGate = "False"
    XNORGateNum = 0
else:
    XNORGate = "True"
    XNORGateNum = 1

print('XNOR Gate output is', XNORGate, 'or', XNORGateNum)

#XOR Gate
if aInput == 1 and bInput == 1:
    XORGate = "False"
    XORGateNum = 0
if aInput == 1 and bInput == 0:
    XORGate = "True"
    XORGateNum = 1
if aInput == 0 and bInput == 1:
    XORGate = "True"
    XORGateNum = 1
else:
    XORGate = "False"
    XORGateNum = 0

print('XOR Gate output is', XORGate, 'or', XORGateNum)

#NOT Gate
if aInput == 1: 
    NOTGate = "False"
    NOTGateNum = 0

else:
    NOTGate = "True"
    NOTGateNum = 1

print('NOT Gate output is', NOTGate, 'or', NOTGateNum)
```

I also tried replacing the `and` in between `aInput` and `bInput` with an `or` which seems to work, but a little tough to repeat usage with the `XOR` and `XNOR` gates:

```
#OR Gate
if aInput == 1 or bInput == 1:
    ORGate = "True"
    ORGateNum = 1
else:
    ORGate = "False"
    ORGateNum = 0

print('OR Gate output is', ORGate, 'or', ORGateNum)

#NOR Gate
if aInput == 1 or bInput == 1:
    NORGate = "False"
    NORGateNum = 0
else:
    NORGate = "True"
    NORGateNum = 1

print('NOR Gate output is', NORGate, 'or', NORGateNum)
```

Comment: Very nice picture. But please post text, not pictures.

Comment: I see you're using if if if else. Try using if elif elif else instead. If it's not clear why, try this link for more info:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271712/difference-between-multiple-ifs-and-elifs-python

Comment: @alfonso haven't learned that yet. I'll give it a shot, thanks!

Comment: I answered your question because I sympathize with being up late and not knowing how to finish your homework, but please do come back and edit your question later. At SO we try and keep the site up to a certain standard for the benefit of everybody who uses it.

Comment: @alfonso I really appreciate it. It's all new and we just started getting into the basics of coding in class, and I just want to understand why certain things don't work and how to fix them. Also, when I tried to insert my code in, it's all jumbled up or doesn't go through. I just made a profile a little over 10 minutes ago. I probably just need to get used to how to use all the things on here o__o

Comment: To paste your code onto the question, copy it from your file and paste it into the StackOverflow text editor. Then highlight the code and press the `{}` button and it'll format as code.

Comment: @alfonso thank you! and I figured out what I had to do if I want to show a small piece of code.

Comment: @coldspeed figured out how to paste my code into my question. check it out. (and sorry for the picture, I  just made a profile here not even 30 minutes ago, still didn't know how this all worked) x(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, try using `elif`. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

```
#OR Gate  
if aInput == 1 and bInput == 1:  
    ORGate = "True"  
    ORGateNum = 1  
elif aInput == 1 and bInput == 0:  
    ORGate = "True"  
    ORGateNum = 1  
elif aInput == 0 and bInput == 1:  
    ORGate = "True"  
    ORGateNum = 1  
else:  
    ORGate = "False"  
    ORGateNum = 0  

print('OR Gate output is', ORGate, 'or', ORGateNum)
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much. I never heard of elif before, so this is awesome :)

Comment: Great, glad it worked. If you want to "accept" my answer, press the check mark by the left-hand side of it. We'll both be rewarded on SO if you do that. You don't have to accept my answer if you think there's a better one, and that'd be fine. But please accept an answer so that the question is closed.

Comment: I most likely will :) I actually ended up using something different for my OR and NOR gates (I posted it in my question above), and used the elif on the XOR and XNOR gates since they are only true or false when inputs are the same. BUT, let's say my professor doesn't accept the elifs (he said to use if statements now that I double checked), how would I use if statements for those two gates (XOR and XNOR)?

Comment: I can guarantee that he won't have a problem with elif. elif is shorthand for "else if". An "if statement" is composed of "if, else if, else". This is such a fundamental part of programming and control structures that he'd have to be extremely unreasonable to not accept.

Comment: I submitted it and double checked that all the gates were showing the correct output. Definitely something great I learned from you (and the other guy who commented as well). Thank you so much for your help and for being welcoming, patient and informing. :)

Answer (score 3):

You may also be interested in the bitwise operators for AND (&), OR (|), and XOR (^):

```
a = int(input('Enter value for A (0 or 1): '))
b = int(input('Enter value for B (0 or 1): '))

print("AND: ", bool(a & b))
print("OR:  ", bool(a | b))
print("XOR: ", bool(a ^ b))
```

This will only output what you expect if the user enters either 0 or 1.

```
Enter value for A (0 or 1): 1
Enter value for B (0 or 1): 1
AND:  True
OR:   True
XOR:  False

Enter value for A (0 or 1): 1
Enter value for B (0 or 1): 0
AND:  False
OR:   True
XOR:  True
```

Comment: Awesome! Didn't know this even existed. Will deff keep it in mind. Makes it super simple :)