# Difference between if statements and elif statements in this context?

Tags: python

```
def is_stylish(pants_colour, shirt_colour):
    """returns a Boolean True or False to indicate whether the given combination is stylish or not"""
    if pants_colour == 'blue' and shirt_colour =='black':
        return True 
    if pants_colour == 'chocolate' and shirt_colour == 'orhre':
        return False
    if pants_colour == 'blue' and shirt_colour == 'ochre':
        return True
    if pants_colour == 'chocolate' and shirt_colour == 'black':
        return False
print(is_stylish('chocolate', 'ochre'))
```

The result of the above program is None. However, if I change it to 'elif statement', the program runs well. I cannot see the difference between both programs.

Here is my basic understanding of the execution.

For the first program: each 'if statement' will be evaluated and if the condition is met, then the block should be executed; if that is the case then the result is `False`.

For the second program: if the preceding condition is met then the following statements would be skipped and lead to the result.

```
def is_stylish(pants_colour, shirt_colour):
    """returns a Boolean True or False to indicate whether the given combination is stylish or not"""
    if pants_colour == 'blue' and shirt_colour =='black':
        return True 
    elif pants_colour == 'chocolate' and shirt_colour == 'orhre':
        return False
    elif pants_colour == 'blue' and shirt_colour == 'ochre':
        return True
    else: 
        return False
print(is_stylish('blue', 'ochre'))
```

Comment: Yes, `if` will be check against all even when the condition is true it will run till the end.. where as in `if elif` it will terminate when the condition is matched. From second code if you remove elif with if then its always gonna return true.. in first program none of your condition matches.

Comment: because think of what happens when **none of your `if` conditions are true**. And then think of what happens in your other function in the same case, except now you have an `else`...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between multiple if's and elif's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271712/difference-between-multiple-ifs-and-elifs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ex. 1.**

> For the first program: each if statement will be evaluated and if the
>   condition is met, then the block should be executed; if that is the
>   case then the result should be False.

This statement does not match what your code is actually doing.

`print(is_stylish('chocolate', 'ochre'))` cannot return `False`, your olny combinations for `False` are:

```
pants_colour == 'chocolate' and shirt_colour == 'orhre'  # !note: 'orhre' is not 'ochre'
pants_colour == 'chocolate' and shirt_colour == 'black'
```

So none of the conditions are met, function doesn't have any other `return`, so it returns None.

**Ex. 2.**

> For the second program: if the preceding condition is met then the
>   following statements would be skipped and lead to the result.

This is correct, in your case, it gets into 
`elif pants_colour == 'blue' and shirt_colour == 'ochre'` and returns True.

**Difference:** the major difference between 2 examples, besides what you have already mentioned, is that in the example 2 you have `else: return False` condition that will cover *all* the other cases, so if none of the conditions before `else` are met, your function will return False, not None.

In the 1st example, if none of the conditions are met, it will just go through all the conditions, won't hit any, and will return None.

Answer (score 1):

Because you **return** at each if statement if the condition is true, there will be only one match both for the two of your code.

For the first program: Each if statement will be evaluate in order, if the condition is met, the `return` code will result in return at that block, and the rest of the code won't be executed. In your case, it will return at line 6, and the rest of the code won't be exectued. If no condition is met, return nothing.

For the second program: If a condition will be met, it acts like the first program. If no condition met, returns a default `False`

Answer (score 1):

I think your *main* problem is that you've mis-spelled `ochre` as `orhre` in the `chocolate` checking line, then used `chocolate/ochre` to test the first one and `blue/ochre` to test the second one. The first one would *also* have worked had you used `blue`.

Fix that little issue and you'll get a non-`None` result from your first bit of code as well, even with `chocolate`.

Your second sample is also *incapable* of returning `None` because either one of the `if/elif` statements will fire, or the `else` will fire. The equivalent in your first sample would be an unconditional `return False` at the end of the function.