# Else statement is always executed

Tags: python, if-statement

I am working at an exercise to practise. This is the code:

```
game_running = True

while game_running:
    user = input("> ")

    if user.lower() == "help":
        print("start - to start the car")
        print("stop - to stop the car")
        print("quit - to exist game")

    if user.lower() == "start":
        print("Car started.")

    if user.lower() == "stop":
        print("Car stopped.")

    if user.lower() == "quit":
        game_running = False

    else:
        print("I don't understand that...")
```

When you, for example, type in: `help`, a help menu appears - *start - to start the car, ...* and so on. When you type in something different (`akfjaksfj`), you get the message *I don't understand that...*.

The problem is - when you type in `help`, the else statement is executed, too - but why? I can't find the problem...

Comment: This should answer your question: [Difference between multiple if's and elif's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271712/difference-between-multiple-ifs-and-elifs)

Comment: The second, third, and fourth `if` statements should be `elif` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use `elif` when chaining if statements like this, so that a match in any of the statements breaks the chain:

```
game_running = True

while game_running:
    user = input("> ")

    if user.lower() == "help":
        print("start - to start the car")
        print("stop - to stop the car")
        print("quit - to exist game")

    elif user.lower() == "start":
        print("Car started.")

    elif user.lower() == "stop":
        print("Car stopped.")

    elif user.lower() == "quit":
        game_running = False

    else:
        print("I don't understand that...")
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score -1):

Try using elif in your statements. Too add to the previous post, try using raw_input instead to avoid an error if other data types are inputted.

```
game_running = True

while game_running:
    user = raw_input("> ")

    if user.lower() == "help":
        print("start - to start the car")
        print("stop - to stop the car")
        print("quit - to exist game")

    elif user.lower() == "start":
        print("Car started.")

    elif user.lower() == "stop":
        print("Car stopped.")

    elif user.lower() == "quit":
        game_running = False

    else:
        print("I don't understand that...")
```

Comment: It's already been answered, avoid duplicates.

Comment: `raw_input` is only needed for Python 2, which is outdated. Anybody should be using Python 3 by now, for which `input` is correct.