# Pycharm (Python 3.8) - How to have input accept both lower and upper case input?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm farly new to coding and I need some help. I'm trying to make a system with a Y/N input. I want to make is so that even if you enter in the input in lower or upper case it still registers the input. I can't really find anything that works as .lower() doesn't work and raw_input is registered as a error, so please help, here's the code.

```
    confirm_user = input("Is this your account? - Admin087 >> ")
    if confirm_user == "Y":
        break
    if confirm_user == "N":
        print('''Shutting down Windows 95 Beta System...''')
        exit()
```

Comment: Try `confirm_user = input("Is this your account? - Admin087 >> ").upper()`

Comment: `confirm_user.lower() == 'y'`. And BTW you should find out the difference between an IDE and a programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just lowercase the logic
you could also edit the code to find if the string starts with a 'y' or 'n'...

```
confirm_user = input("Is this your account? - Admin087 >> ")
if confirm_user.lower() == "y":
    print("yes")
elif confirm_user.lower() == "n":
    print('''Shutting down Windows 95 Beta System...''')
else:
    print('woops')
```

also, why to use elif: [Difference between multiple if's and elif's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271712/difference-between-multiple-ifs-and-elifs)

Answer (score 0):

the easiest it would be to use `"string".upper()` method to force input to always be in uppercase. Then just check if the answer in uppercase is right.
Best Regards

Comment: It is better to use `lower()` for the lesser known fact that for some international characters `c.upper().lower() != c`.