# What is different if and elif?

Tags: python

if is strong than elif in code?
or if and elif is same?

```
if a[number_counter] == answer:
    a_count+=1
elif b[number_counter] == answer:
    b_count+=1
elif c[number_counter] == answer:
    c_count+=1
```

this code has problem than I change code to

```
if a[number_counter] == answer:
    a_count+=1
if b[number_counter] == answer:
    b_count+=1
if c[number_counter] == answer:
    c_count+=1
```

than code not has problem.

Comment: Your conditions aren't mutually exclusive - `answer` could be equal to any or all of them, so the *logic* is different depending on whether or not you use a single [`if` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#if) (case 1) or multiple separate `if` statements (case 2). Which is *correct* depends on your context.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between multiple if's and elif's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271712/difference-between-multiple-ifs-and-elifs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's  different.

It basically else if but concated to elif. if you use elif you check the same condition and if one is met it exits.

If you use ifs the whole time it checks each if statement whether or not the previous one was true.

It's just normal Python Syntax.

```
x = 0
if x == 0:
#do something
#if True it doesn't check the rest
elif x ==1:
#do something
#if true if doesn't check the rest
elif x==2:
#do something
#if true doesn't check the rest
else:
#if none of these are True this gets exucuted
#do something

#It checks all these if statements whether or not one is true. 
if x==1:
#do something 
if x==2:
#something
```

Comment: Not the same. When it is only if then it checks all the conditions. With elif it stops checking once it matches even a single condition.

Comment: Already added it in.