# Difference Between ELIF and Nested If in Python?

Tags: python

Attempting to learn Python, but slightly confused. When would I use a nested IF statement over an ELIF? The course instructor provided the top code while my code is written on the bottom. The purpose of the program is to determine if a year is or is not a leap year:

**instructor**

```
year = int(input("Which year do you want to check? "))

if year % 4 == 0:
    if year % 100 == 0:
        if year % 400 == 0:
            print("Leap year.")
        else:
            print("Not a leap year.")    
    else:
        print("Leap year.")
else:
    print("Not leap year.")
```

**mine**

```
year = int(input("Which year do you want to check? "))

if year % 4 == 0:
    print("Leap year.")
elif year % 100 == 0:
    print("Leap year.")
elif year % 400 == 0:
    print("Leap year.")
else:
    print("Not leap year.")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between multiple if's and elif's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271712/difference-between-multiple-ifs-and-elifs)

Comment: Try them both with the year 1900?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't understand the question. They do completely unrelated things, so I have no idea how anyone should answer "what's the difference".

Comment: As for why you *should* do things one way or another - that's subjective (assuming both versions are correct code, and that you don't have an objective measurement like time taken), and [we don't address that here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 4):

`elif` is short for `else if`.  The `elif` will only be evaluated if no prior `if` or `elif` in the chain was true.

Your version of the code doesn't work because any year that is divisible by 4 will execute the first block; none of the `elif`s can ever be true, and the `else: print("Not leap year.")` can't happen once that initial `if` is true.

```
year = int(input("Which year do you want to check? "))

if year % 4 == 0:
    print("Leap year.  (Maybe!)")
elif year % 100 == 0:
    print("This will never get executed because 100 is a multiple of 4.")
elif year % 400 == 0:
    print("This will also never get executed for similar reasons.")
else:
    print("Not leap year.")
```

```
Which year do you want to check? 1904
Leap year.  (Maybe!)
Which year do you want to check? 2000
Leap year.  (Maybe!)
Which year do you want to check? 2001
Not leap year.
Which year do you want to check? 2100
Leap year.  (Maybe!)
```

The output of the instructor's code for the same inputs is:

```
Which year do you want to check? 1904
Leap year.
Which year do you want to check? 2000
Leap year.
Which year do you want to check? 2001
Not leap year.
Which year do you want to check? 2100
Not a leap year.
```

Note the "not a leap year" result for 2100 (which is correct).

Answer (score 1):

Any time you flatten nested conditionals like your instructor's you're essentially `and`ing all of the previous levels to each condition:

```
if A:
    if B:
        if C:
            foo
        elif D or E:
            42
        else:
            bar
    else:
        baz
else:
    wooble
```

Starts to look like:

```
if A:
    if A and B:
        if A and B and C:
            foo
        elif A and B and (D or E):
            42
        elif A and B:
            bar
    elif A:
        baz
else:
    wooble
```

And then we get rid of all but the last `if`, and compress the indentation to a single level:

```
if A and B and C:
    foo
elif A and B and (D or E):
    42
elif A and B:
    bar
elif A:
    baz
else:
    wooble
```

The nested conditional can be cleaner since we're not repeating conditions, but it can also be more difficult to follow logically, whereas the single level example makes every condition very explicit.

Translating your instructors code using the same method:

```
if year % 4 == 0:
    if year % 100 == 0:
        if year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 == 0 and year % 400 == 0:
            print("Leap year.")
        elif year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 == 0:
            print("Not a leap year.")    
    elif year % 4 == 0:
        print("Leap year.")
else:
    print("Not leap year.")
```

Cleaning it up:

```
if year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 == 0 and year % 400 == 0:
    print("Leap year.")
elif year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 == 0:
    print("Not a leap year.")    
elif year % 4 == 0:
    print("Leap year.")
else:
    print("Not leap year.")
```

But knowing math we know that we can remove redundant checks.

```
if year % 400 == 0:
    print("Leap year.")
elif year % 100 == 0:
    print("Not a leap year.")    
elif year % 4 == 0:
    print("Leap year.")
else:
    print("Not leap year.")
```

And there's the same check done in **one** level of indentation.

### One More Thing

To take this "algebra" of conditionals one step further, the above leap year example has two branches that lead to the same result. Let's algebra this up by using symbols:

- `Q` = `year % 400 == 0`
- `H` = `year % 100 == 0`
- `F` = `year % 4 == 0`
- `N` = `print("Not leap year.")`
- `Y` = `print("Leap year.")`

```
if Q:  Y
elif H:  N
elif F:  Y
else:  N
```

Consecutive branches that have the same outcome can be `or`ed together. But, any conditions that occur between them we have to `and` the negative of them into the condition.

```
if Q or F and not H:  Y
elif H:  N
else:  N
```

And knowing that we can `or` together consecutive branches with the same result, we can reduce this further. But if one of those branches is `else`, we can just use the `else`.

```
if Q or F and not H:  Y
else:  N
```

Comment: Understood. So in summation, I would use the multiple if when I’m try to declare multiple parameters for the same variable and elude when I’m checking one parameter at a time?

Comment: It's really a bit of an opinion thing. The "flat" conditional can be good for avoiding repetition, but I find that each level of indentation represents an additional level of mental exertion to keep track of what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use `elif`s instead of nested `if`s, then you should order the conditions in order of specificity.

```py
year = int(input('year'))

if year % 400 == 0:
    print('Leap')
elif year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0:
    print('Leap')
else:
    print('Not Leap')
```

Seeing that two branches have the same outcome, we can `or` the conditions together to simplify.

```
if year % 400 == 0 or (year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0):
    print('Leap')
else:
    print('Not Leap')
```

Comment: You use the elif if you want to see if it matches something else that is not the original condition. you use a nested if if you want to see if something else matches in addition to the original condition. (see also @Chris's answer)

Comment: understood. thank you so much for the clarification, this really helps me!