# Code prints input instead of checking for it

Tags: python

```
name = input("Who are you? ")
print("Are you here to test me?")
if input("y"):
    print("I'll banish you " + name + ", out of this realm")
if input("n"):
    print("Good. Now leave.")
```

I used Python in Visual Studio Code.

When executed, after I enter my name, the terminal literally says "y". I don't want it to literally say "y". When I type anything else, the code still prints! I only want it to print when I type 'y' or 'n'. Also, it'll execute the code in the order given, not with the corresponding letter (so if I say n, it'll give the results of y.) Please I am a beginner and I want to at least know what's up so I can learn from my mistakes.

Comment: Think on this: you are calling a function `input` and you are telling _that function_ to take a parameter `'y'`. What are you expecting `input` to do with that parameter?

Comment: [Difference between multiple if's and elif's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271712/difference-between-multiple-ifs-and-elifs)

Comment: Also, look how do you use `input` the first time and the last two. What happens every time? Why would you expect it to work different each time?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the corrected code -

```py
name = input("Who are you? ")
print("Are you here to test me?")

answer = input() # assign the user's input to a variable

if answer == "y": # compare the variable against the desired values
    print("I'll banish you " + name + ", out of this realm")

if answer == "n":
    print("Good. Now leave.")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name = input("Who are you? ")
answer =input("Are you here to test me? ").lower()
if answer == 'y':
    print("I'll banish you " + name + ", out of this realm")
elif answer == 'n':
    print("Good. Now leave.")
```

Some outputs:

```
Who are you? Aj
Are you here to test me? y
I'll banish you Aj, out of this realm

Who are you? Aj
Are you here to test me? Y
I'll banish you Aj, out of this realm

Who are you? Aj
Are you here to test me? n
I'll banish you Aj, out of this realm

Who are you? Aj
Are you here to test me? N
I'll banish you Aj, out of this realm
```

Answer (score 0):

The `input()` function takes a single parameter, which is the prompt to show to the user. If you want to check the users input, you need to compare against the value returned by the `input()` function.
You will also want to consider what happens if the user enters a response in a different case, or of a value you don't expect.

In this example, the response to the second prompt is immediately converted to lowercase, and then we take only the first character to use for the comparison.  I've also added a branch to handle if the user input isn't 'y' or 'n'.

```
name = input("Who are you? ")

# Just use input for this prompt instead of a print command
# .lower() changes the string returned by input to lowercase
# strings are indexed like arrays, so [0] will return the first character
answer = input("Are you here to test me? ").lower()[0] 

if answer == "y":
    print("I'll banish you " + name + ", out of this realm")
elif answer == "n":
    print("Good. Now leave.")
else: #Answer wasn't yes or no.
    print("I can't understand you.")
```

```
Who are you? Bob
Are you here to test me? Yes
I'll banish you Bob, out of this realm

Who are you? Bob
Are you here to test me? no
Good. Now leave.

Who are you? Bob
Are you here to test me? Maybe
I can't understand you.

Who are you? Bob
Are you here to test me? 12345
I can't understand you.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
name = input("Who are you? ")
myinp = input("Are you here to test me?")
if myinp.startswith("y"):
    print("I'll banish you " + name + ", out of this realm")
else:
    print("Good. Now leave.")
```